# User input text box

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, global-variables

I'm having a bit of trouble of getting the JavaScript code right. I need some help on what goes where and how it's supposed to look.

This is what I have so far in my script.

```
<script>
  var i = "1";
   var listItem = "";
  function processInput() {
 if (i <= 5) //Comparison operator//
      document.getElementById("listItem").innerHTML = (i <= 5);
  </script>
```

Here is my question:

Create a function called processInput(). Within the function create an if statement that runs if the value of i is less than or equal to 5. The if statement should perform the following actions:

- Set the value of the listItem variable to the string "item" concatenated with the value of i.
- Set the content of the element with an id equal to listItem to the value of the element with the id or toolbox.
- Set the value of the element with the id of toolbox to an empty
  string.

---

I'm not sure if I'm setting this up right. I have tried w3Schools and the information on their site seemed to be unhelpful/unclear.

Comment: To be honest I think you just need to study and learn more JavaScript. Right inside your if-statement you are setting the HTML of the element `listItem` to the value of the condition `(i <= 5)` which would be `true` if it runs (since it's the same condition of the `if`). Also `i` is a string and not a number and the function is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: w3schools is not a very good tutorial site, it has many mistakes.

Comment: Your instructions describe exactly what you need to do. Just translate each action to code. So look up how to concatenate strings in Javascript. Then assign that result to the variable. Then use that variable (not a quoted string) in the call to `getElementById`.

Comment: @Barmar It's actually [somewhat decent for beginners](http://www.w3fools.com/). Although there are better sources, I would recommend [MDN's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) OP. Although MDN tends to be a bit more complex and may be a little harder to beginners to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going step by step:

- Set the value of the `listItem` variable to the string "item" concatenated with the value of `i`.

  ```
  var listItem = "item" + i; // + performs string concatenation
  ```
- Set the content of the element with an id equal to `listItem` to the value of the element with the id of `toolbox`.

  ```
  document.getElementById(listItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolbox").value;
  ```
- Set the value of the element with the id of `toolbox` to an empty string.

  ```
  document.getElementById("toolbox").value = "";
  ```

So the whole function should look like:

```
function processInput() {
    if (i <= 5) {
        var listItem = "item" + i;
        document.getElementById(listItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolbox").value;
        document.getElementById("toolbox").value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your goal behind this but that's how it's done.
remember that "i" will stay the same because you're not incrementing it
just study more javascript and i hope this helps you buddy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
var listItem = "";
var listItemElement = document.getElementById("listItem");
var toolbox = document.getElementById("toolbox");
processInput();

function processInput() {
    if (i <= 5) {
        listItem = "item " + i;
        listItemElement.innerHTML = toolbox.innerHTML;
        toolbox.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using the value of `listItem` in the call to `document.getElementById()`.